# Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:3! in DPOTrainer with ec2 G5 12X Large

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer, llm

```
import os
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset
from transformers import (
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    AutoTokenizer,
    TrainingArguments,

)

from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM
from trl import DPOTrainer
from peft import LoraConfig

hf_auth = ""
peft_model_path = 'test/'
dataset = load_dataset(
    "test_classification",
)
print("Dataset loaded:", dataset)


def format_instruction(vignette: str):
    return f"""<s>[INST]{vignette.strip()} Generate given Vignette class and explain the reason for class.[/INST] """.strip()


def generate_instruction_dataset(data_point):

    return {
        "chosen": data_point["chosen"],
        "rejected": data_point["rejected"],
        "prompt": format_instruction(data_point["prompt"])
    }


def process_dataset(data: Dataset):
    return (
        data.shuffle(seed=42)
        .map(generate_instruction_dataset)
    )


dataset = process_dataset(dataset)

print("Dataset processed:", dataset)

compute_dtype = getattr(torch, "float16")

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    llm_int8_threshold=6.0,
    llm_int8_has_fp16_weight=False,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
)

print("Loading base model:")

model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path,  # location of saved SFT model
    device_map="auto",
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
)

print("Loading reward model:")

model_ref = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path,  # same model as the main one
    device_map="auto",
    quantization_config=bnb_config,

)

print("Loading tokenizer:")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path, use_auth_token=hf_auth, trust_remote_code=True, device_map="auto")


output_dir = "dpo/output/"
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    remove_unused_columns=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
)

print("Lora config added")

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    r=64,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
)

print("DPO trainer initialized:")

dpo_trainer = DPOTrainer(
    model,
    model_ref,
    args=training_args,
    beta=0.1,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    # eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    max_length=1024,
    max_prompt_length=512,
)

torch.set_grad_enabled(True)

print("DPO trainer started:")

dpo_trainer.train()
print("Training done")
```

I am use G5 12X Large instance for this training it has following GPU's GPU 0: NVIDIA A10G GPU 1: NVIDIA A10G GPU 2: NVIDIA A10G GPU 3: NVIDIA A10G

But with start of dpo_trainer.train() following error will occur:

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:3!

---

Moreover i used `ref_model=None` and `device_map={"": PartialState().process_index}` in both model and tokenizer. Then it gives :

```
output = torch.nn.functional.linear(A, F.dequantize_4bit(B, quant_state).to(A.dtype).t(), bias)
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 172.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 22.02 GiB of which 142.19 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 21.88 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 19.27 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.35 GiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)
```